# Perl: Search through all directories that have a specific string in them

Tags: regex, perl

I want to search through a folder looking for a file lets say i'm searching through /Applications/ looking for target.exe:

the problem I have right now is that it takes too long to search through everything in /Applications/ (about 70 seconds)

I want to narrow my search to something like: /Applications/Example-Version but version is different on every Example directory

How can I use File::Find to search through only directories that have the path /Applications/Example-X ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use File Globbing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
@files = </Applications/Example-Version*/target.exe>;
foreach $file (@files) {
  print $file . "\n";
}
```